# High CPU usage while parse pdf document with Apache tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

We are using apache tika **1.13** for content extraction.

allocated **6GB** to application.

With heavy pdf around 2 GB, the application takes 95% to 100% CPU and application became unresponsive.

code to extract content from PDF file

```
public String extractPDFContent(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        File file = new File(filename);
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        tika.setMaxStringLength(-1);
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
        PDFParserConfig config=new PDFParserConfig();
        config.setSortByPosition(true);
        context.set(PDFParserConfig.class,config);
        ContentHandler handler = null;
        try(InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(url)) {
            handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
            parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            log.error("Exception:"+ex.getMessage(),ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return handler.toString();
    }
```

as we need all content so passed **-1** for below

```
tika.setMaxStringLength(-1);
new BodyContentHandler(-1)
```

refer following queries:

1. is there any way to load partial document and extract content more efficiently?
2. Provided option in [Streaming_the_plain_text_in_chunks](https://tika.apache.org/3.0.0-BETA/examples.html#Streaming_the_plain_text_in_chunks) will chunk output only. Is there any other streaming option?
3. How to efficiently(CPU/memory) parse large PDF document with tika?
4. Is there any config like use temp file for processing like pdfbox

   PDDocument.load(new File("sample.pdf"), MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly())

also planning for upgrade tika.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache Tika? And are you doing OCR on the PDF?

Comment: Using a temp file would make it even slower. How about sharing the file?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr ur right using temp filem it might be slower, but it may reduce memory foot print.
Due to security policy not able to share file. If it replicates in sample file then will surely share file.

Comment: @Gagravarr we are not doing OCR.

Comment: Try upgrading to a much more recent version of Tika, then try again

Comment: I agree with @gagravarr and Tilman -- try a more modern version of Tika. I'd add that If you are parsing enough files, you will hit problematic files, and you need to isolate parsing in a separate jvm. See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/The+Robustness+of+Apache+Tika